# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED

Tags: python, anaconda

The following issue has been asked a lot on the internet in general and also here on stackexhchange.

**Unfortunately, many of the issues I have found on the internet refer to an SSL problem, which I don't have.**

I just download and freshly installed anaconda on my windows 10 OS.

I am trying simply to create a new anaconda environment with the following command:
`conda create --name anaconda_test_env python=3.7`

and I get the following error

```
(base) C:\Users\USER1>conda create --name anaconda_test_env python=3.7
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
(base) C:\Users\User1>
```

I am behind a corporate firewall and proxy and from what I have read on the internet this could be the problem.

However, **the strange thing is that I can access the files at `https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64` from a browser.**

Could you help me solve the problem or run some tests to understand if the corporate firewall is actually the problem?

EDIT: I am sure now that it is a problem of corporate firewall/proxy. Indeed, I tried to run the same thing without being connected to the company VPN and it worked without problems. I think that I will need to ask the system administrator to "open" the anaconda URLs.

Thanks!